# Is there a timeout function for receiveChan?

Tags: haskell, cloud

In Cloud Haskell, the `expect` function has a timeout cousin called `expectTimeout`.  Is there also a timeout function for `receiveChan` (for the type safe channel)? [Source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/distributed-process/0.2.1.4/doc/html/src/Control-Distributed-Process-Internal-Primitives.html)

Currently, my application will wait indefinitely for a reply, therefore if a process dies my application will be in a deadlock state, thus, it would be nice if I could set a timeout so that it ignores processes that have died.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `receiveChanTimeout` in version 0.4.2

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/distributed-process/0.4.2/doc/html/Control-Distributed-Process.html